How to Monitor and Analyze Server SEO Metrics Before Downgrading from 8-Core to 4-Core CPU (Apache+PHP+MySQL)
I’m managing a website running on an 8-core server with Apache, PHP, and MySQL, but it feels overprovisioned for our current traffic. To optimize costs, I’m considering downgrading to a 4-core CPU. However, I want to monitor specific metrics before and after the migration to ensure performance and SEO rankings aren’t negatively affected.
I already use Cloudflare Pro with standard caching enabled (no custom rules), which helps offload some traffic.
Here are the key metrics I plan to track:

Core Web Vitals: Largest Contentful Paint (LCP), First Input Delay (FID), Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)
Google Search Console (GSC): Response time in Crawl Stats to detect potential crawl budget issues.
Time to First Byte (TTFB): Measuring with tools like WebPageTest or curl.
Peak CPU Usage: During high-traffic periods, using tools like top, htop, or vmstat.
500-Level Server Errors: Monitoring error logs for server overload or database timeouts.

Questions:

Are these metrics sufficient to evaluate the impact of reducing CPU cores?
Should I include additional metrics like memory usage, database query times, or others?
How can I log the output from tools like top or vmstat to analyze trends over time?

If you’ve handled a similar downgrade, I’d love to hear your experience—especially regarding how fewer CPU cores affected:

Performance during traffic spikes.
SEO factors like crawl budget and Core Web Vitals.

I’m also open to other suggestions to ensure I can revert the downgrade quickly if the metrics degrade significantly.
